# how is min-width calculated in media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {

    #hello { background:red;}

}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:600px) {

    #hello { background:green;}

}
```

I use http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ to test my site and when I check the 320x480 the media query is not working.

Any ideas?

Am also using this http://codebomber.com/jquery/resizer/ and get the same problem.

min-width:320px means the viewport must be at least 320px or wider, right?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your media query, so we'll need more information to troubleshoot. One thing I would add is that the max-width is unnecessary if you're using another min-width in conjunction with it that overrides the style at 481px.

Comment: I dont what other info i can give you, this is it, a basic html page with this style.

Comment: Is it possible to actually view the page somewhere?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PW6E9HPx

Comment: and the css http://pastebin.com/HERjHAis

Comment: a much simpler css, sorry about that http://pastebin.com/mhdJVWph

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble, but i tried the same code with another browser and it's working correctly, i dont know what it the problem.

Thank you kinakuta, for your interest.

Comment: I'm sorry again, but i'm having a real trouble testing the page in various online tools, can anyone recommend one that works the same in all browsers. i am testing with the ones suggested here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/ and i have different results

Comment: which browsers are you getting different results in (i.e. which are working and which aren't?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me.

Here is is recreated on CodePen - http://codepen.io/justincavery/full/lbtBk

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;}
/* Style the body where there is no media queries available */    
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px){
  body {background-color: red;}
/* Style the body if the viewport is at least 320px or at most 480px */
}
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:600px){
  body {background-color: green;} 
/* Style the body if the viewport is at least 481px or at most 600px */
}
@media (min-width:601px){
  body {background-color: pink;} 
/* Style the body if the viewport is at least 601px */
}
```